# Authentication Method Policies for Identity Experience Framework Custom Policy

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-ad-b2c, multi-factor-authentication

There is a preview available for 'enhanced registration' in AAD-B2C, enabling Fido2 Security Key's and MS Auth app.
How can I programmatically enable this or add it to a Experience Framework Custom Policy?
I want simple 2FA with both Fido2 and MS Auth app (passwordless).

There doesn't look to be any clear announcements or documentation available for this, there is [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/cool-enhancements-to-the-azure-ad-combined-mfa-and-password/ba-p/354271) post, but it's about Azure AD, not B2C. However, in the Azure AD B2C blade, under Security, it shows Authentication methods (Preview), per below screenshot.
Is this only for Azure AD (not B2C)?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share us any document/information about  'enhanced registration'.It will help us to better understand the question.

Comment: @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity, the only information i have is in the blue info box in the screenshot above and the additional info I added. Where it states "Click here to enable users for the enhanced registration preview.". John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not available to AAD B2C, it is displayed by an  unfortunate side effect of this feature not needing a license. The menu was supposed to only allow modifying the smart lockout properties, which are within Authentication Methods.